# Appending an html element with multiple class names using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to append this list item `<li><i class="fa fa-star" ></i></li>`  to an unordered list using JQuery`$("ul.star-rating").append("<li><i class="fa fa-star" ></i></li>")` however I get an error that there a missing ")".
I assume that I should escape the white-space between the classes "fa"&"fa-star".I don't know if my assumption is correct and I wanted to know how can I achieve such a result:
 `<ul class="star-rating">
         <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
  </ul>`

Comment: You should escape the quotes or mix single and double quotes: `$('ul.star-rating').append('<li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>')`

Comment: I would suggest using double quotes in html and single quotes in javascript for systematic approach, readability and to have less worry about escaping.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your use of quotes in this part:

```
"<li><i class="fa fa-star" ></i></li>"
```

You need to escape the `"fa fa-star"` quotes. Otherwise it's like jamming several different objects together `"<li><i class="`, literal `fa fa-star` and `" ></i></li>"`. Or you could just single quotes on the outside.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 $("ul.star-rating").append("<li><i class='fa fa-star'></i></li>");
```

You are using double quotes inside a string that terminates the argument literal of append method.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

You have to use single quotes when you start with double quotes or otherwise

`$("ul.star-rating").append("<li><i class='fa fa-star'></i></li>")`